# Usage of "inspite of"

Tags: word-usage

Which one of the following sentences is correct?

> Inspite of unwell, she went to school.

or

> Inspite of being unwell, she went to school.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of expressing the kind of contrast that you illustrate.

One is the expression **in spite of** (Note that it is three words, not two)

The other is the word **despite**, which means much the same.

In both cases you need to use **being** in your examples.

So you should write:

> In spite of **being** unwell, she went to school

Another way of putting it is:

> > In spite of feeling unwell, she went to school

or, using **despite**

> Despite **being/feeling** unwell, she went to school.

You will find their usage and the nuances between them illustrated at:

(https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/gramatica/gramatica-britanica/in-spite-of-and-despite)